# What should be the ideal batch size for [image data] if local machine has NVIDIA GTX 1050 4 GB graphic card?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

As the question specify I need to know what is the Ideal batch size if I want to train a neural network such as VGG16, VGG19, Xception, Inception, Densenet on a local machine which has a GTX 1050 4 GB NVIDIA GPU? Consider two scenarios one with a training image dataset with size 2000 images and another scenario where you have training data more than 10,000.

Comment: Depends on the size of the images ;)

Comment: You just try it out until you get no OOM errors. Start with powers of 2 like 16, 32, 64, 128. Once you get OOM lets say at 128, subtract the initial batch size over and over until you get no OOM (112 , 96, 80 ... ). You can even subtract arbitrary numbers but I'm obsessed with power of 2s and I'll do it this way.